# Azure notification hub with hybrid mobile Application exception. remote server returned an error

Tags: cordova, azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

Hi Guys I am new to Azure Hub. So my question is when the notification is picked up from the worker role and push to the notification hub i am getting an below exception:

```
ProcessNotification exception System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.ArgumentException: 
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. The Apns certificate is expired. 
.TrackingId:xxxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx_xxx,TimeStamp:3/24/2017 7:51:56 AM ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.NotificationRequestAsyncResult`1.<GetAsyncSteps>b__3(TAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
   at Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace:
```

Can anyone tell me Where i am doing wrong and where i can configure this expired certificate again.

Answer (score 1):

To configure the expired Apple certificate from Azure Portal see [Configure your Notification Hub for iOS push notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-ios-apple-push-notification-apns-get-started#configure-your-notification-hub-for-ios-push-notifications).

Answer (score 0):

We are facing same error reported by Azure Notification hub. It's ocassionaly thrown even if the certificate is valid and 'test send' from Azure portal works without problems.